# Installing Shapely in Python (Spyder)

Tags: python, gis, shapely

Good morning.
I need to install the Shapely package for using Python for GIS analysis.
I searched online and I found that it should be enough to write this line:

`conda install -c conda-forge shapely`

I'm a total beginner and it is not clear to me if I need to put this line in Python's IDLE or if it is enough to write it in Spyder (which I'm learning to use).
I tried both options and the result is always the same:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you have any ideas/suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you write in your [command prompt](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/a-beginners-guide-to-the-windows-command-line/) on Windows. This assumes that you have [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) installed. You may have better luck using `pip`, which is bundled with Python by default. The command you type in the command prompt is `pip install shapely`. Hope it works for you, good luck!

Comment: Uh thank you. I get lost in the easy stuff ahah, slowly I will learn!

Comment: No worries, you'll get there, and you'll enjoy it all along!